# WPF Texblock cant go on MultipleLines

Tags: c#, wpf

currently i'm having an issue with the wpf textblock. Can't seem to make the text go multiple line.If it doesn't fit on the screen it just goes off the screen. I saw a couple ppl suggested that i put it in a ViewBox, but that just makes the font shrink and the text becomes so small its unreadable.

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,40,0,0">

        <Label Content="Name" Padding="0" FontSize="20"
               BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}"
               BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="TitleBlock" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15" Margin="0,0,0,15" />
        <Label Content="Author" Padding="0" FontSize="20"
               BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}"
               BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="AuthorBlock" Text="Just Some Name " FontSize="15" Margin="0,0,0,15" />
        <Label Content="Date Published" Padding="0" FontSize="20"
               BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}"
               BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="DateBlock" Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}" FontSize="15" Margin="0,0,0,15" />
        <Label Content="Summary" Padding="0" FontSize="20"
               BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}"
               BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="SummaryBox" Text="{Binding Summary}"  FontSize="15" Margin="0,0,0,15" />

    </StackPanel>
```

I tried using grid instead of StackPanel but it still doesnt solve the problem.

**In short**, my question is how do i make it so that the text in the textblocks can go on multiple lines if it doesnt fit the screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Simply set `TextWrapping` property of `TextBlock` to `Wrap` or `WrapWithOverflow` as desired to wrap content of an element

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="Long Text..." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
   ```
2. Or put your elements into a `WrapPanel` to wrap elements in a container

   ```
   <WrapPanel>
       <TextBlock>Long Text 1</TextBlock>
       <TextBlock>Long Text 2</TextBlock>
   </WrapPanel>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use TextWrapping property of the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="test text" Width="100"
TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
```